# Error when use useNativeDriver in React Native Animated

Tags: animation, react-native, react-animated

When I use `useNativeDriver` in React Native Animated

```js
state = {
    chevronUp: new Animated.Value(-50),
};
```

```js
Animated.spring(this.state.chevronUp, {
    toValue: 50,
    friction: 5,
    useNativeDriver: true,  // <----- this line
}).start();
```

and render

```js
<Animated.View style={{bottom: this.state.chevronUp,position: "absolute", right: 20, width: 50, height: 50}}>
    <Icon name="chevron-up" size={28} color="#666"/>
</Animated.View>
```

these errors give me

> Style property 'bottom' is not supported by native animated module

and

> Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: To which property are you applying this animation?  Can you add some sample code and context showing where you're using this?  Not all properties are animatable ...

Comment: Can you please share where this animation code running in the component lifecycle?

Comment: Same error here, have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to use `"translateY"` property instead of `"bottom"` which is supported by the native driver, so your initial value will look like this:

```js
state = {
    chevronUp: new Animated.Value(50),
}

Animated.spring(this.state.chevronUp, {
    toValue: -50,
    friction: 5,
    useNativeDriver: true,  // <----- this line
}).start();
```

and in the render method:

```js
<Animated.View style={{translateY: this.state.chevronUp,position: "absolute", right: 20, width: 50, height: 50}}>
    <Icon name="chevron-up" size={28} color="#666"/>
</Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error comes from [validateTransform](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c3d072955024824d7ff6113fc9f642d25c462f16/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper.js#L219) function inside React Native lib.You can check the `TRANSFORM_WHITELIST` in [NativeAnimatedHelper](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c3d072955024824d7ff6113fc9f642d25c462f16/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper.js#L186) for the property supported by animated module.

Currently, there are these props supported

```js
const TRANSFORM_WHITELIST = {
  translateX: true,
  translateY: true,
  scale: true,
  scaleX: true,
  scaleY: true,
  rotate: true,
  rotateX: true,
  rotateY: true,
  rotateZ: true,
  perspective: true,
};
```

You'd better use `translateY` instead of `bottom` here.

```js
<Animated.View style={{translateY: this.state.chevronUp,position: "absolute", right: 20, width: 50, height: 50}}>
     <Icon name="chevron-up" size={28} color="#666"/>
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: If i have multi-input, should i declare multiple variables for every position?

Comment: sorry, can't understand you